# How set variable from object in another class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some class(AppCompatActivity), object and lateinit var in this object.
I get some value in class and need to initialize this lateinit var in object
How can i do that?
Tried:

---

in class:

---

ObjectName.varName = varFromClass

Answer (score 0):

Don't use lateinit in an object class,

You have to use, default constructors like :

```
data class Door(val doorType : Int, val title : String, val location : String) {

constructor() : this(1,"Door A", "Admin Building")
```

}

To set an element from your object, just do :

```
val mDoor = Door()
mDoor.title = "new title"
```

Comment: I dont use data class, i need to use object(singlton).
''Constructors are not allowed for objects" IDE tells

Comment: any suggestions, please?

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to use lateinit var? Can you just set the var to a default value, and add a setter to put your value?

Comment: Because i dont have default value. I need to initialize variable in object from textfield.TextInputEditText in activity